# How do you interpret this in Verilog, when the repeat and posedge are written inside each other like this?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
  repeat(9)@(posedge clock);
  ref = ref_count +10;           //posedge and repeat are used together

  repeat(ref)@(posedge ref_clk);
  repeat(3)@(posedge b_clk);
```

Answer (score 3):

The repeat construct simply replicates the accompanying procedural statement that follows. So

```
repeat(3) @(posedge b_clk);
```

becomes

```
begin 
  @(posedge b_clk);
  @(posedge b_clk);
  @(posedge b_clk);
end
```

If the expression used as the `repeat` argument is not a constant, it gets evaluated once before replicating the statements. (This was recently clarified in an [upcoming SystemVerilog LRM version](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=7358)).

Comment: what does the 3 @(posedge b_clk) mean? what do they signify as far as their waveform is concerned? How would the entire code work if you could let us know.

Comment: You would have to show more code where you saw the repeat statements. I'm assuming this is a behavioral model or retrench.  `repeat(3)@(posedge b_clk);` means it would block three clock cycles before executing the next statement.